# Passing arguments from a text file to console app?

Tags: c#, .net

Passing console input from a file.

I'm passing two file paths here using console, But I don't want user to open console app
and copy paste the path, instead of I want a configuration file where I can set 
the paths which I'm entering below.

How can i pass arguments from a text file and just execute the console app?

```
        Console.Write("Enter Error File Path: ");
        string errorfilepath = Console.ReadLine();
        string[] ErrorFile = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(errorfilepath);

        Console.Write("Enter Archive File Path: ");
        string archivefilepath = Console.ReadLine();
        string[] ArchiveFile = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(archivefilepath);

        Furthur processing which is working fine..
```

Comment: If I understand your question correctly -- and correct me if I'm wrong -- Right now you're asking for a file path from the console and then reading it which is redundant -- consider just reading from a set file name like config.txt or something

Comment: Or save the input in a text file and pass it to your application executable: `yourApplication.exe < path\to\input.txt`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have lots and lots of options for what you're trying to accomplish.

I would suggest giving your application [Settings in Visual Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wabtadw6.aspx).  That will create appropriate entries in App.config where you can enter the two file paths that you want.

Then, in your program, you can read the configured paths using code like:

```
string errorfilepath = Properties.Settings.Default.ErrorFilePath;
```

If a user wants to change the default that you provide, they can edit App.config (which will actually be named YourAppName.exe.config).

The app.config file will have lines that look like this:

```xml
<applicationSettings>
    <MyProgram.Properties.Settings>
      <setting name="ErrorFilePath" serializeAs="String">
        <value>C:\Temp\MyErrorFile.txt</value>
      </setting>
    </MyProgram.Properties.Settings>
</applicationSettings>
```

*NOTE: You will have to add a reference to System.Configuration to do this.*

Comment: Okay, I generated settings.setting file with my two inputs based on app.config generated, so which file shall user edit to pass the error file path? app.config or settings.setting?

Comment: The user edits app.config. Note that when you compile your app, app.config is renamed to YourApplication.exe.config.